# Is it possible to make attribute is dynamic

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to make attribute is dynamic if possible guide me how to do

```
driver.findElement(By.**name**("username"))
```

See the above scenario, in this case i need to make attribute **"name"** as dynamic one. Is it possible to achieve this if possible please give code for that how to do or give logic to do

Thank you in advance

Comment: get element by xpath `'//*[@'+ attrName +'="username"]'`

Comment: How you would decide which locator to be used?

Comment: What's the use case for it? What are you trying to get out of it?

Comment: I have 1 class say "Allfunctiondef" it is having method                       public WebElement LBE_By_ID(String ID) {
  return(driver.findElement(By.id(ID)));
  
 }

Comment: I have 1 class say "ABC" it is having method                       public WebElement LBE_By_ID(String ID) {
  return(driver.findElement(By.id(ID)));
  
 } it is defining class and i have one more class say "XYZ" in this i am creating object of ABC class and through that object i will call LBE_By_ID by passing parameter                                              ABC a=new ABC();                                               a.LBE_By_Xpath(".//*@id='content']/div[2]/div/div[2]/button").click();i need to make attribute "id" dynamic one

Comment: @ Purus  I will give one parameter in method like a.LBE_By_ID("ID", "username"); "ID" is attribute type and "username" is element path

Answer (score 0):

There is no such inbuilt feature in Selenium. But with core java you can achieve this as shown below.

```
public WebElement getElement(String type,String identifier){

    WebElement element;

    if (type.equals("ID")) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
    } else if (type.equals("cssselector")) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(identifier));
    } else if (type.equals("tag")) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.tagName(identifier));
    } else if (type.equals("classname")) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.className(identifier));
    }
}
```